# Why do some of my react applications have no style when switching route?

Tags: reactjs

I noticed those applications that I made when I have `import './componentStyle.scss';` in the component will have no style for a brief moment when I switch route.

Isn't this what react recommended (conditional styling)?

Those projects that I have a main scss file imported directly to index.js doesn't have this issue.

Comment: You are most likely using Webpack with css loader and style loader, which will make the content flash in development since the CSS is added to the document through the JavaScript code. Depending on your setup it will not be like that when you build your assets for production.

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? How are you changing routes? There was an issue with create-react-app: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6399, not sure if it's related, need more info...